# $\mathbb{R}^2$ is not a subspace of $\mathbb{C}^2$?

Tags: complex-numbers, vector-spaces, real-numbers

I found a answer to a question with an answer which shocked me a little, so I wanted to make sure it is correct.

The answer told, that if $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{C}^2$, then
$$i(1,1)=(i,i)$$
belongs to $\mathbb{R}^2$ which is a contradiction.

I agree that this is a contradiction, but being a subspace in this case mean that there is a $(0,0)$ element and the set is closed under addition and scalar multiplication. The $\mathbb{C}^2$ includes all the elements of $\mathbb{R}^2$, so why it cannot be a subspace?

Is there a condition that space and subspace must be defined over the same field?

It is from Sheldon Axler "Linear Algebra Done Right" pg. 24, ex. 5.

Answer found here https://linearalgebras.com/1c.html.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, subspaces by definition have the same scalar field.

Comment: Note that it says "**complex** vector space". If it was asking over a **real** vector space, the answer is yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ is a $\mathbb{R}$-vector-space of dimension 2.
- $\mathbb{C}^{2}$ is a $\mathbb{C}$-vector-space of dimension 2, and an $\mathbb{R}$-vector-space of dimension 4.

As an $\mathbb{R}$-vector-space, $\mathbb{R}^2 < \mathbb{C}^2$. As a $\mathbb{C}$-vector-space, $\mathbb{R}^2 \not< \mathbb{C}^2$.

Answer (score 0):

When we write $\mathbb{C}^2$ we assume, by convention (in the context of linear algebra), that we refer to the usual vector space on this set. The vector space is more than just the set itself: it's the set, and the scalar field, and the addition operation, and the scalar multiplication operation, all rolled into one. If we change any one of these, then we actually have a different vector space. Yes, the set of vectors, $\mathbb{C}^2$, might be the same, but the vector space is more than just this set.

The other answer, by preferred_anon, captures this well. We can simply restrict the scalar field to the subfield $\mathbb{R}$ (and restrict the scalar multiplication operation accordingly), and we get a different beast. Instead of a vector space with dimension $2$, we now have a vector space of dimension $4$, despite the underlying set being identical.

So, if you care considering whether a subset of a vector space is a subspace, it's important you take into account the extra pieces of information inherent in a vector space, beyond the set itself: the scalar field, the addition defined, and the scalar multiplication defined.

In the usual interpretation of $\mathbb{C}^2$ (which it's safe to assume that we're working in, unless told otherwise), $i$ is a perfectly valid scalar, and $(1, 1)$ is a perfectly valid vector in this subset ($\mathbb{R}^2$). Their product, as defined by the usual scalar multiplication operation on $\mathbb{C}^2$, is $(i, i)$. This is not an element of the subset, so the subset is not a subspace of this vector space.

Of course, if we change the interpretation of $\mathbb{C}^2$ to be the usual vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ (suggested by Don Thousand and preferred_anon), then $i$ is no longer a valid scalar, so computing $i(1, 1)$ would be undefined (and hence totally irrelevant). In this case, we can show that $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a subspace of this (non-standard) $\mathbb{C}^2$ vector space.